# Logic for creating multiple rows for BIOSRelDate and BIOSVersion combination

Tags: xml, xslt

Could you please advise on how I can build the XSLT logic using the below XML? I need to be able to sort by BIOSReldate and create two rows for BIOSReldate and BIOSVersion combination.

My final output should have the following attributes in a .CSV

```
Description, Class, HardwareID, Vendor, BIOSRelDate, BIOSVersion

<!---
```

There are two BIOSRelDate and BIOSVersion instances and need to generate them as multiple rows

```
 <Device Count="1" Description="xxxx System Management BIOS Driver"   
 Class="System" DeviceType="Smbios">
      <HardwareIDs>
        <ID Value="ROOT\mssmbios" />
      </HardwareIDs>
      <Properties>
        <Vendor Value="American Megatrends Inc." />
        <BIOSRelDate Value="11/02/2016" />
        <BIOSVersion Value="C1043.BS.4A16.AH1" />
        <BIOSRelDate Value="10/02/2017" />
        <BIOSVersion Value="C1043.BS.4A25.AH1" />
      </Properties>
</Device>

Below is what I tried -

<xsl:apply-templates select="Device/Properties">
    <xsl:sort select="BIOSRelDate" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
...
<xsl:template match="BIOSRelDate">
    <!--Duplicate all Properties data for each BIOSRelDate-->
    <Device>
        <xsl:value-of select="../*[not(self::BIOSRelDate)] | ."/>
    </Device>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What have you tried? When transforming hierarchy to table structure you need to identify the deepest level that will become the table row. Then you iterate over those   elements gathering the rest of information trasvering the hierarchy from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/Device">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <xsl:text>Description, Class, HardwareID, Vendor, BIOSRelDate, BIOSVersion&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- COMMON DATA -->
    <xsl:variable name="common">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Description"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Class"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="HardwareIDs/ID/@Value"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Properties/Vendor/@Value"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- GENERATE ROWS -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Properties/BIOSRelDate">
        <!-- SORT BY YEAR -->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(@Value, 7, 4)" data-type="number"/>
        <!-- SORT BY MONTH -->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(@Value, 1, 2)" data-type="number"/>
        <!-- SORT BY DAY -->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(@Value, 4, 2)" data-type="number"/>
        <!-- OUTPUT -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$common"/>        
        <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::BIOSVersion[1]/@Value"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
Description, Class, HardwareID, Vendor, BIOSRelDate, BIOSVersion
xxxx System Management BIOS Driver,System,ROOT\\mssmbios,American Megatrends Inc.,11/02/2016,C1043.BS.4A16.AH1
xxxx System Management BIOS Driver,System,ROOT\\mssmbios,American Megatrends Inc.,10/02/2017,C1043.BS.4A25.AH1
```

---

Note that I assumed that your date format is `MM/DD/YYYY`. Your example is ambiguous in that regard. If it's `DD/MM/YYYY`, make the necessary adjustment.