# How to get nested nodes from XML to CSV via XSLT

Tags: for-loop, templates, xslt, nested, tags

I have XML like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
   <Header>
      <MessageId>{70BF3A9B-9111-48D8-93B4-C6232E74307F}</MessageId>
      <Action>http://tempuri.org/example/find</Action>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <MessageParts>
         <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <pain.001.001.02>
               <GrpHdr>
                  <MsgId>AB01029407</MsgId>
                  <CreDtTm>2020-05-07T11:23:08</CreDtTm>
                  <NbOfTxs>2</NbOfTxs>
                  <CtrlSum>4598</CtrlSum>
                  <Grpg>MIXD</Grpg>
                  <InitgPty>
                     <Nm>MY COMPANY Ltd1</Nm>
                     <Id>
                        <OrgId>
                           <TaxIdNb>GB 823825133</TaxIdNb>
                        </OrgId>
                     </Id>
                  </InitgPty>
               </GrpHdr>
               <PmtInf>
                  <PmtInfId>AB01029407</PmtInfId>
                  <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
                  <PmtTpInf>
                     <SvcLvl>
                        <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
                     </SvcLvl>
                  </PmtTpInf>
                  <Dbtr>
                     <Nm>MY COMPANY Ltd</Nm>
                     <PstlAdr>
                        <AdrLine>Address Line 1</AdrLine>
                        <AdrLine>Address Line 2</AdrLine>
                        <Ctry>CB</Ctry>
                     </PstlAdr>
                  </Dbtr>
                  <DbtrAcct>
                     <Id>
                        <IBAN>98</IBAN>
                     </Id>
                  </DbtrAcct>
                  <DbtrAgt>
                     <FinInstnId>
                        <BIC>ABC123</BIC>
                     </FinInstnId>
                  </DbtrAgt>
                  <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
                  <CdtTrfTxInf>
                     <PmtId>
                        <EndToEndId>Not-Provided</EndToEndId>
                     </PmtId>
                     <Amt>
                        <InstdAmt Ccy="CAD">2198.00</InstdAmt>
                     </Amt>
                     <CdtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                           <BIC>SWIFT01</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                     </CdtrAgt>
                     <Cdtr>
                        <Nm>Creditor Name</Nm>
                        <PstlAdr>
                           <AdrLine>tests</AdrLine>
                           <AdrLine>Chicago</AdrLine>
                           <Ctry>US</Ctry>
                        </PstlAdr>
                     </Cdtr>
                     <CdtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                           <IBAN>98</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                     </CdtrAcct>
                     <RmtInf>
                        <Ustrd>1345</Ustrd>
                     </RmtInf>
                  </CdtTrfTxInf>
                  <CdtTrfTxInf>
                     <PmtId>
                        <EndToEndId>Not-Provided</EndToEndId>
                     </PmtId>
                     <Amt>
                        <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">2400.00</InstdAmt>
                     </Amt>
                     <CdtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                           <BIC>SWIFT01</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                     </CdtrAgt>
                     <Cdtr>
                        <Nm>Creditor Name1</Nm>
                        <PstlAdr>
                           <AdrLine>tests</AdrLine>
                           <AdrLine>Chicago</AdrLine>
                           <Ctry>US</Ctry>
                        </PstlAdr>
                     </Cdtr>
                     <CdtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                           <IBAN>98</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                     </CdtrAcct>
                     <RmtInf>
                        <Ustrd>123456765</Ustrd>
                     </RmtInf>
                  </CdtTrfTxInf>
               </PmtInf>
            </pain.001.001.02>
         </Document>
      </MessageParts>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I have XSLT like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
    xmlns:ns2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>  
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates
    select="ns1:Envelope/ns1:Body//ns2:pain.001.001.02//ns2:GrpHdr"/>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ns2:GrpHdr">
      <xsl:value-of select="ns2:CreDtTm"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ns2:NbOfTxs"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ns2:CtrlSum"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ns2:Grpg"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ns2:InitgPty/Nm"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text> <!-- Line Return -->
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this XSLT I am getting only one set..but not able to go beyond one group of elements. Output i got is:

```
2020-05-07T11:23:08,2,4598,MIXD,
```

This looks correct only. But i wanted almost all specific nodes. I could not able to get the inner nested elements from a template.

The desired output is:

```
2020-05-07T11:23:08,2,4598,MIXD,MY COMPANY Ltd1,GB 823825133,AB01029407,TRF,SEPA,MY COMPANY Ltd,Address Line 1,Address Line 2,CB,98,ABC123,SLEV,Not-Provided,2198.00,SWIFT01,Creditor Name,tests,Chicago,US,98,1345
2020-05-07T11:23:08,2,4598,MIXD,MY COMPANY Ltd1,GB 823825133,AB01029407,TRF,SEPA,MY COMPANY Ltd,Address Line 1,Address Line 2,CB,98,ABC123,SLEV,Not-Provided,2400.00,SWIFT01,Creditor Name1,tests,Chicago,US,98,123456765
```

I am newer to XSLT. Can anyone help with this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"
xmlns:ns2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02">
<xsl:output method="text"/>  

<xsl:template match="/ns1:Envelope">
    <!-- data from header -->
    <xsl:variable name="header" select="ns1:Body/ns1:MessageParts/ns2:Document/ns2:pain.001.001.02/ns2:GrpHdr" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$header/ns2:CreDtTm"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$header/ns2:NbOfTxs"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$header/ns2:CtrlSum"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$header/ns2:Grpg"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$header/ns2:InitgPty/ns2:Nm"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$header/ns2:InitgPty/ns2:Id/ns2:OrgId/ns2:TaxIdNb"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <!-- data from pmt -->
    <xsl:variable name="pmt" select="ns1:Body/ns1:MessageParts/ns2:Document/ns2:pain.001.001.02/ns2:PmtInf" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$pmt/ns2:PmtMtd"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$pmt/ns2:Dbtr/ns2:Nm"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <!-- CONTINUE HERE -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this assumes there is only one record in the input XML and therefore only one row in the output CSV. Your XML is structured in a way that allows multiple nodes of the same kind at various level of the hierarchy. If you want to reflect this in your CSV, you need to decide which node will represent a record and adjust the stylesheet so that it creates a separate row for each instance of such node - see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55311500/3016153

Comment: Thank you @Michael. I wast trying like this just now:
    <xsl:apply-templates
    select="ns1:Envelope/ns1:Body//ns2:pain.001.001.02/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ns2:InitgPty//*"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ns2:InitgPty//*//*"/>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
And i got this:
2020-05-07T11:23:08,2,4598,MIXD,MY COMPANY Ltd1, GB 823825133
Yet to structure it in the expected expected .
Mean while i got the solution from you.. a real great and quick reply. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Michael,
Could you please tell me to loop it based on CdtTrfTxInf
I want to loop the CdtTrfTxInf & display all data along with the GrpHdr & Dbtr info.
desired:
2020-05-07T11:23:08,2,4598,MIXD,MY COMPANY Ltd1,GB 823825133,AB01029407,TRF,SEPA,MY COMPANY Ltd,Address Line 1,Address Line 2,CB,98,ABC123,SLEV,Not-Provided,2198.00,SWIFT01,Creditor Name,tests,Chicago,US,98,1345
2020-05-07T11:23:08,2,4598,MIXD,MY COMPANY Ltd1,GB 823825133,AB01029407,TRF,SEPA,MY COMPANY Ltd,Address Line 1,Address Line 2,CB,98,ABC123,SLEV,Not-Provided,2400.00,SWIFT01,Creditor Name1,tests,Chicago,US,98,123456765

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Either edit your question, or - preferably, since this is a new requirement - post a new one. Note that the link I provided above shows a solution to a similar problem; try to adapt it to your situation before asking for assistance.

Comment: Created new one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61868052/for-each-in-xslt-loops-through-only-first-record